# i can't reference a String that exists

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to run this code:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

but the `R.string.default_web_client_id` part isnt working (Cannot resolve symbol 'default_web_client_id').

i know that the 'default_web_client_id' string exists, but it isnt at the String XML, its in a generated 'values.xml'

[image: print of the values.xml and the path to it]

am i doing something wrong or it should be working?

Comment: this is error is for some time when you run the app it will automatically gone

Comment: you don't have to put your `default_web_client_id` when you adding firebase AUTH dependency it will automatically generate that string

Comment: i thought that and tried to run, i didnt work

Comment: what error occurred can you show your log cat

Comment: that "values.xml" is the automatically generated xml ;-;

Comment: @ciao mendes Yes!

Comment: I think your app will not going to crash anywhere. Just androids studio 's IDE will produce that error. You can Ignore that.

Comment: oh, i couldnt see that, thanks

Comment: If my answer is helpful please accept as a answer ✅ and If you think It will help future developers you can Up vote this answer 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your app will not going to crash anywhere. Just Android Studio's IDE will produce that error. You can ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it inside

> /app/src
> instead of
> /app/build folder
> else it won't work because /app/build folder is a misc folder that contains files that are compiled when you build the apk

Comment: it's a generated xml, i can't change it

Comment: i mean you should put that values.xml in /app/src/main/res/values folder also it should be accessed like R.values.default_web_client_id because the value is stored in values.xml file and not in string.xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand that why not put the string into strings.xml? (app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml) or put it into a separate class that contains some constant variables.

I use a class named `Configs.java` to save these variables.

```
public class Configs {
    ... 
    public final static String WEB_CLIENT_APP_ID = "XXX"
    ... 
}
```

```
val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(Configs.WEB_CLIENT_APP_ID)
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
```